# In SQL Server, how can I identify "double" strings and correct?

Tags: sql, sql-server

How can I find strings in a column that are doubled-up and correct them?  I feel like there is an easy answer to this I just can't think of it.

**Example:**
I want to find instances of a repeating string, example "SolonSolon", and then update the column to "Solon".

**Update:**
They're always the same.  No extra characters, but might have a space as part of the repeating value.  Other examples would be...

"PlacePlace", "TreeTree", "OrangeOrange", "TravisMemorialHSTravisMemorialHS", "Texas HSTexas HS"

Comment: Will they *always* be the same string repeated?Will they *always* be the same string repeated?

Comment: Or could it be that just parts of the string of the string that is repeated?

Comment: Perhaps a string a string could have multiple parts repeated parts repeated too?

Comment: Seems like we need more examples examples if I am honest honest. (I'm done now.)

Comment: Can you provide some typical examples. Eg what happens with "SolonSolong" or "ASolonSolon" or "Solon Solon" or "Solon, Solon" etc

Comment: Not sure it's  that simple. Baden-Baden is not Baden.

Comment: And a yoyo is not yo and a mumu isn't a mu

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can check if the string is equal to the first half replicated.

```
SELECT LEFT(YourCol,LEN(REPLACE(YourCol, ' ', 'x'))/2)
FROM YourTable
WHERE YourCol = REPLICATE(LEFT(YourCol,LEN(REPLACE(YourCol, ' ', 'x'))/2),2)
```

The reason for the `REPLACE` of spaces with `x` before calculating the `LEN` is because trailing spaces are ignored by this function. You can also use the technique in @lptr's answer for this but an edge case will be if the string was `varchar(8000)` and already 8000 characters long in which case concatenating an extra character won't do anything (`LEN(SPACE(8000) + 'x')` is `0`).

Comment: This is perfect.  Elegant solution to what seems to have been a such a touchy question!  Thanks for the help.  I wasn't aware of "REPLICATE".

Comment: I will steal something from @lptr's answer (+1) though. Their answer currently handles strings with trailing spaces better due to the `+'.'` and then subtracting 1. Trailing spaces aren't counted by `LEN`

Comment: I used a different method rather than outright theft

Answer (score 2):

..replace the first half of the value with an empty string..if there is nothing left..the value consists of two equal parts

```
select *, substring(c, 1, (len(c+'.')-1)/2)
from
(
values
('solosolo'), ('yoyo'), ('andand'), ('1212'),(' . .'),
('ababc'), ('onetwoone')
) as t(c)
where replace(c, substring(c, 1, (len(c+'.')-1)/2), '') = '';
```

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative.  The query removes inner spaces using `REPLACE(str_col, ' ', '')`, removes leading/traling spaces using `TRIM`, and checks to make sure the first half of the string equals the second half.

```
select left(no_spaces.str_col, v.str_len/2) 
from foo f
     cross apply (values (replaced trim(f.str_col), ' ', '')) no_spaces(str_col)
     cross apply (values (len(no_spaces.str_col))) v(str_len)
where no_spaces.str_col=replicate(left(f.str_col, v.str_len/2), 2);
```